# Alternative for python-mathdom

Tags: python, mathml

I'd like to convert a MathML expression to an equation string in python, for which the [MathDOM module](http://mathdom.sourceforge.net/) should be good for.

An example would be:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <lambda>
     <bvar><ci>A</ci></bvar>
     <bvar><ci>B</ci></bvar>
     <apply>
         <plus/>
         <ci>A</ci>
         <ci>B</ci>
     </apply>
   </lambda>
</math>
```

should map to "A + B". This should obviously work with more complex expressions.

However, it is quite old and not working properly with new versions of the xml module (trying to include the wrong module structure, etc.)

Does anyone know useful alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution so far: [libsbml](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/python-api/)

```
from libsbml import *
ast = readMathMLFromString(xmlString)
f = FunctionDefinition(2,4)
f.setMath(ast)
kl = KineticLaw(2,4)
kl.setMath(f.getBody())
kl.getFormula()
```

Ok for me since I'm already working with it but far from a general solution.

Comment: is it impossible for general solution?

Comment: it is not supporting on Python 3.4. Only have support for 2.6 and 2.7