# Mathml to math notation in python

Tags: python, math, mathml

I have a `mathml` expression suppose:

```
<math><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>
```

I need to make **x^2** from this say **math notation**.

I checked a lot and find out certain solutions but all refers the opposite thing, ie, making mathml from math notation.

[Reference](http://mathdom.sourceforge.net/)

I need just the opposite.

Making **math notation** from `mathml`.

Note: I need a generalised thing that should work on all conditions of `mathml`?

**Python version: 3.4**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for python-mathdom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188082/alternative-for-python-mathdom)

Comment: My python version is 3.4. Sadly that library support only on 2.6 and 2.7

Comment: @Santhucool do you or your colleagues have the skill to port this library to Python 3.4?

Comment: @shuttle87 it will be a tedious task!! Why python does not have version compatibility? Thats y java is still the best!!

Comment: @Santhucool, if it's worth it to your team you could always port if need be, there's tools to help that, for example the 2to3 tool. This particular library happens to interest me and I'd be happy to port it given the means (translation: some nominal amount of money). The reason Python 3 broke backwards compatibility was to fix core problems with the language that couldn't otherwise be fixed. As someone who uses Java professionally the backwards compatibility is great but we have to recognize that it does come with a very real cost, that being the enormous amount of cruft in the language.

Comment: Not sure if anyone's still interested, but, as nearly as I can tell, MathML appears to be more of a formatting language, not a "function representing" language. Having said that, I might be able to help by running the MathML through Mathematica and then converting it w/ some tools I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below assumes that you have Maple installed. Maple can parse MathML code that can be converted later using the CodeGeneration package to the following programming languages:

```
C, CSharp, Fortran, IntermediateCode, Java, JavaScript,
Julia, LanguageDefinition, Matlab, Names, Perl,
Python, R, Save, Swift, Translate, VisualBasic
```

Here is an example:

- Copy the MathML code.
- Open Maple, and paste. You will see this message box:

[image]

- Clicking on Yes, you will see:

[image]

- Load the CodeGeneration package, and call  the Python function:

```
with(CodeGeneration)
Python(cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2 = 1, resultname = "expr1")
```

The result will be:

```
expr1 = math.cos(x) ** 2 + math.sin(x) ** 2 == 1
```

You can adjust the result accordingly.